# how to execute a cmd line when prompts for password with java

Tags: java, cmd

Hy,

I try to dump a postgresql database from my java application.

In cmd it goes ok:

```
pg_dump -U user database>outfile.sql
```

and CMD prompts for password

To access this command line from my java:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pg_dump -U user database>outfile.sql");
```

and now it waits for password.

I tried with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String[])...` but nothing.

Somehow, I must set the parameter 'password' in `.exec()` method,

pg_dump statement does not accept password in it's command line..

Answer (score 2):

thanks Max,

I tried this

```
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
    bw.write("password"); 
    //bw.eriteLine();
    bw.flush();
```

but still nothing. I used InputStreamReader to see errors or messages from cmd execution, and nothig. It still waits for 'Password'.

But I had another solution :

```
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /C\"pg_dump -U user -W db>outfile.sql\"");
```

so the black prompter opens with 'Password:'. write the password, hit enter and it goes off.

that's enough for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Missed to press "Enter".
This modification did the trick for me:

```
bw.write("password" + "\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

Full working solution:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));
bw.write("password\n"); 
bw.flush();
```

Tried to update @cortexiphan solution, but my edit was rejected.

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect the standard input of the process as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563337/how-to-redirect-stdin-to-java-runtime-exec).

Essentially, they make use of the `Process.getInputStream` method and write to the stream this method returns (e.g. with a BufferedWriter).

You get the neccessary `Process` object returned by the `exec()` method.