# How to write to an ongoing console

Tags: java, io, console, writer

I am making a java program that takes an input and puts it to another console (windows). The thing is, the other console is a Minecraft server that is in the middle of running. The console has a `>` and it is waiting for me to type in a command. If I type `help` in manually, for example, it will run the help command and return the output. Then it will remain with the `>` waiting for another command until it gets stopped. How can I write to this type of console from a Java process? I tried BufferedWriter, PrintWriter, and OutputStreamWriter. I've been making getting the output stream by running `Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar server.jar");` How can I write to this console? (Reading works fine)

Comment: You can send bytes to the minecraft server's input stream (the thing that gets populated when you physically type into the console). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2563432/5601284

Comment: You can't send things to input stream... You write to Outputstream... I also mentioned that I tried that and it did not work

Comment: So use `getOutputStream()` and write data to it. The data you write is read as standard input by the server. Your description of what you've tried is vague

Comment: Trying Runtime.getRuntime().exec("commandblahblahblah").getOutputStream().write("stuf") did not work.

Comment: You also need to flush the stream and close it https://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html

Comment: If I close the stream I am unable to write more afterwards I will need to be able to send more commands after the first one. My program has an input section where you input commands, you see.